# Finding the steady-state temperature given temperature along the rim of unit disk

Tags: complex-analysis

Consider the unit disk in the plane. We fix the temperature along the rim by the function:

$u(e^{i\theta}) = sin(\theta)$ if $0 \le\theta \le\pi$, $0$ otherwise. Find the steady-state temperature at $z=\frac{1}{7}$

I believe the approach is to use Dirichlet or Poisson formula, but I'm not exactly sure.

Comment: Never mind formulas – what *property* is the function $u$ supposed to have (in the interior of the disk)?

Comment: @GerryMyerson is $u$ supposed to be constant inside the disk?

Comment: That seems unlikely, doesn't it? Shouldn't it be larger, close to spots on the rim where it's large, than close to spots on the rim where it's small?

Comment: Yes, I agree with that @GerryMyerson. I guess I'm not sure what property you are referring to that $u$ should have.

Comment: Do you have any study materials which relate values in the interior to values on the boundary, for certain types of functions? (or for certain physical contexts?)

Comment: should I look at the mean/maximum value property? @GerryMyerson

Comment: Do they relate values in the interior to values on the boundary, for certain types of function?

Comment: I hope you haven't given up.

Comment: I guess you have. Too bad.